# Metadata tags input form

Tags: visual-studio, 2013, tags

I want to add a input field for a tags via visual studio and I'm wondering, how this field is called inside VS:

[image: Metadata tag input field]

does anyone know how this field is called and where to find this in Visual studio 2012?

thanks in advance
Jürgen

edit:

To clarify my comment on the post from Vardhaman Deshpande.

The "FieldMetadata" looks like this:

[image: Metadata field]

As I mentionend in the comment, after deploying there is nothing to see. Furthermore, where can I add the reference to a specific metadata "term store"? i.e. this:
[image: terms]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a `Taxonomy` or `Managed Metadata` field. You can add this field through visual studio either declaratively or programmatically.

**Update:**

Here is a link to create the the Metadata field programmatically:
http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/02/create-managed-metadata-field.html

And see here to add it to the New Form:
http://sharepointlearningcurve.blogspot.in/2010/04/sp-2010-configure-and-use.html

Comment: Before I wrote this post, I tried different metadata and taxonomy fields none of them where displaying me anything. I.e. I tried the "fieldMetadata", TaxonomyFieldControl and TaxonomyWebTaggingControl, but none of them displayed me an input form. Is there anything else I have to pay attention to? p.s. I make a small update on my post to clarify things

Comment: Please see the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here is a post I have answered 
[Add managed metadata column via visual studio 2012](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/61250/add-managed-metadata-column-via-visual-studio-2012/61253#61253).

May be this helps

Andrew

Comment: Thanks, that was my question as well, but in this case, this is something different :) the approach from Vardhaman seems to work, still trying.